# Adding max id from a different table to a query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I need to join the max(id) with is a bigint (and a primary key) from one table to another table.  So, if the max id is 1234567890, then I would want the results to be:

```
name, max_id
'foo', 1234567890
'bar', 1234567890
'noo', 1234567890
'boo', 1234567890
'zoo', 1234567890
```

My first thought was just to write a function and market it as `STABLE`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_max_id() RETURNS bigint AS
$$
DECLARE
    result bigint;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'entering get_max_id';
    SELECT INTO result max(id) FROM mytable;
    RETURN result;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE;
```

Then I called it via a SQL statement like:

```
SELECT name, get_max_id() FROM a_really_big_table;
```

But, from my `raise notice`, it seems like this is getting called for each each record in `a_really_big_table`.

What is the best way to write this so that I can keep the PostgreSQL from doing a lookup on `mytable` for each row in `a_really_big_table`?

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.1

Comment: Please show the definitions of "one table" and "another table"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a solution?

```
=# SELECT name AS name,
          (SELECT MAX(id) FROM your_table) AS max_id
   FROM really_big_table;

       name       │ max_id
──────────────────┼─────────
 44e5f8fc1f75fad2 │ 5307021
 97fc0aa3a5e3da98 │ 5307021
 ccb83afb938ad758 │ 5307021
 523bf25914e5c9c0 │ 5307021
 d2362badeb2eb7ea │ 5307021
 b6e0b87df6d41523 │ 5307021
 da754db1fa226453 │ 5307021
 865d0e177cb0a3e8 │ 5307021
 5904a07a273d8cba │ 5307021
 952c75ef37d47dab │ 5307021
(10 rows)
```